# Very Basic jquery call isn't working at all

Tags: jquery

I feel so bad having to post this. But, I have been banging my head to understand why this simple code doesn't work on any of my browsers. IE or Chrome or FF.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#click").click(function(){
    $("#para").hide();
  })
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="para">Hai Rama Raju</p>
<button id="click">Click to hide the text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And it doesn't work at all !!! I checked the Javascript on browser, it's enabled. I tried downloading the jquery file and still the issue persists. No clue !!!

Comment: If you checked the JavaScript in the browser, then you should have seen a console error.

Comment: @Sparky I think he means he checked that JavaScript is enabled. But yes, learning how to use the error console would be important.

Comment: Thank you guys. Like the solution below said ... I missed something as trivial as putting a closing bracket. :(

Answer (score 5):

You're not closing the document ready with a `)`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#click").click(function(){
    $("#para").hide();
  })
}) // this line
```

Comment: I wish I could 'Like' your reply a 100 times. Such a shame on me !!! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $("#para").hide();
    });  // <-- Missing semicolon here...
});      // <-- Missing ) and semicolon here...
```

You might wanna try this too:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $("#para").toggle();
    });
});
```

With no parameters, the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method simply toggles the visibility of elements.